# During the start of java code with appium and winappdriver got invalid argument message

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, winappdriver

I'm quite new in automation, so I tried to do some simple example with starting notepad in combination with appium and winappdriver.

this is the code which is used in java(Eclipse IDE)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver;



public class WinAppDriverTest {
     static WindowsDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); //org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
        appCapabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
        driver = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appCapabilities);
    }

}
```

This is the contents of pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.simple.automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenProjectSimple</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I try to execute the java file I get some Error message in console

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 400. Message: Bad capabilities. Specify either app or appTopLevelWindow to create a session 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-someName', ip: '170.25.221.122'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:app=C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe, appium:automationName=Windows, platformName=windows}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {app: C:\Windows\System32\notepad..., appium:automationName: Windows, platformName: windows}}]
Capabilities {app: C:\Windows\System32\notepad..., appium:automationName: Windows, platformName: windows}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:133)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:182)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:154)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:101)
    at io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver.<init>(WindowsDriver.java:50)
    at WinAppDriverTest.main(WinAppDriverTest.java:19)
```

in WinAppDriver I can see this message

```
Windows Application Driver listening for requests at: http://127.0.0.1:4723/
Press ENTER to exit.


==========================================
POST /session HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 229
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: appium/8.5.1 (selenium/4.10.0 (java windows))
X-Idempotency-Key: 30ebcf38-12e5-45d9-8461-b307b5c6c7d9

{
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
      }
    ],
    "alwaysMatch": {
      "appium:app": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe",
      "appium:automationName": "Windows",
      "platformName": "windows"
    }
  }
}
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 141
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":100,"value":{"error":"invalid argument","message":"Bad capabilities. Specify either app or appTopLevelWindow to create a session"}}
```

Thank you for advice

I have  also replaced in java replaced ip address with some other ip which I can see in cmd -> ipconfig
But it didn't solve my problem

`driver = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appCapabilities);`

Answer (score -1):

For beginners it's much comfortable to use C# and visual studio.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).